# TVS Diode Selection for automotive application

Tags: esd

I'm looking to protect the input of a 5v buck regulator with an absolute maximum input voltage of 20v. The circuit is running a car.

The typical input of the regulator is 12v and at max, the circuit will pull 500mA.

I'm looking at the [Nexperia PESD12VS2UT](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/916/PESDXS2UT_SERIES-1599676.pdf) with has the following characteristics:

Vbr Min: 14.7
Vbr max: 15.3
Clamping Voltage @ 1A: 19v

My question is: Does this TVS provide (more or less) enough wiggle room for the circuit to operate under normal conditions without breaking down? I understand that vehicle charging systems run at 14v, but I haven't been able to find a part that clamps under 20v AND has a breakdown over 15v.

Comment: Are you connected to the car 12V bus? You should check out load dumps. The spec for those is 85V with huge currents, which will immediately explode any tvs diode you use (different for regulated systems with supression)

Comment: @BeB00 - I'm connected to the 12v line, yup. It appears that load dumps are rare (or otherwise suppressed) in the system because I have unprotected units that have survived jump starts, etc. Still, I don't want to chance it.

Comment: A TVS is only as good as the surge specification it intended to handle. Do some research to find out what that surge specification might be.

Comment: A TVS can be protected with a proper joule rating for load dump spec with a choke if necessary as the voltage spike rises when the battery and alternator are weak and the ACU shuts off the current must be absorbed by the ESR in the battery. I’ve tested the joule ratings but used bigger TVS parts